# shutil.move() slower than os.remove() + os.rename()

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I noticed that when I want to move a file 'a' and overwrite the destination 'b' os.remove('b') and then os.rename('a','b') is a lot faster than shutil.move('a','b').

I've read [that](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shutil.html#directory-and-files-operations):

> If the destination is on the current filesystem, then os.rename() is used. Otherwise, src is copied (using shutil.copy2()) to dst and then removed. In case of symlinks, a new symlink pointing to the target of src will be created in or as dst and src will be removed.

but why doesn't it use os.remove() also?

Example (1st time using timeit, sorry if I have any mistakes):

```
import os,timeit
os.chdir('c:\python')
def myMove(a,b):
    os.remove(b)
    os.rename(a,b)

with open('src1', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(os.urandom(350000000))
with open('src2', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(os.urandom(350000000))
with open('dest1', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(os.urandom(350000000))
with open('dest2', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(os.urandom(350000000))

print('shutil.move(): %.3f' %timeit.timeit('shutil.move(os.path.join("c:\python","src1"),os.path.join("c:\python","dest1"))','import shutil,os.path', number = 1))
print('os.rename(): %.3f' %timeit.timeit('myMove("src2","dest2")','from __main__ import myMove', number = 1))
```

prints:

> shutil.move(): 0.81
>
> os.rename(): 0.052

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `os.rename(src, dst)` works if `src` and `dst` are on different filesystems. And it does not work on Windows if `dst` exists.

Just as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) say

Comment: 3.3+ adds `os.replace` for overwriting the destination. Like `rename`, it calls `MoveFileEx` on Windows, but with the flag `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING`. To move across file systems requires a copy and delete, for which `win32api.MoveFileEx(src, dst, win32con.MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED|win32con.MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING)` is probably faster than `shutil.move`.